# Values get converted to UNICODE when sent by Python in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a small problem when my code is retrieved by javaScript from Python, i get unicode values to my script where my browser gives an error in the developer console.

The script inside my archive.html page -

```
<script>
    var results = {{myposts}};
    console.log(results);
</script>
```

My Python code -

```
def archive(request):
    test = ["a","b","c"]
    t = loader.get_template("archive.html")
    c = Context({'myposts' : test})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

I tried `c = Context({'myposts' : simplejson.dumps(test)})` , but it gave the problem.
My browsers give me and arror **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &** and my console shows my array with unicode values `[&#39;a&#39;, &#39;b&#39;, &#39;c&#39;]`

How do i make it look like - `["a","b","c"]`

What do i change in my Python code or JavaScript

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Your values are being HTML escaped; this is not a Unicode problem. :-)

Comment: You might get ASCII or ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 but you will never get Unicode. Unicode ist just the idea, the realization in memory (or on disk) differs.

Comment: @Matthias thanks for the tip, i am still learning my way through web development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's getting HTML-escaped on output. What if you do this?:

```
var results = {{ myposts|safe }};
```

(Use with caution -- you may want to perform some escaping depending where the data is coming from.)

Comment: It works perfectly, without needing to any changes to my python code

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the template:

```
<script>
    var results = {{ myposts|escapejs }};
    console.log(results);
</script>
```

EDIT:

And in the view:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def archive(request):
    test = ["a","b","c"]
    t = loader.get_template("archive.html")
    c = Context(simplejson.dumps({'myposts' : test}))
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Comment: I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in my browser console and my var results looks like this "var results = [\u0022a\u0022, \u0022b\u0022, \u0022c\u0022];"

Comment: The edited version gave me null value to my variable "var results = ;" and my browser console throws an error. But when i just did this on my JavaScript http://jsfiddle.net/gfCWp/3/ it worked perfectly (forgive me for my noob style coding )